# Generate normal distributed random integer from 1-10 and use in simulink

Tags: matlab, simulink

I'm new at Simulink and Matlab,
Trying to use the MATLAB action where I have a customer Entity, want to simulate the arrival rate of these customer's and needs to generate a random number from 1-10 normally distributed.

Tried to do it like this, but it seems wrong.

```
n = 1; % However many numbers you want.
dt = randi([1, 10], [1, n])
```

Any idea, to generate this random number , so I can assign dt to that?

Comment: Do you want a normal or a uniform random number? You write normal, which is not per se possible with your limits `[1,10]` as it spans the entire x-axis. If you meant uniform, that is exactly what you get with the command that you have written.

Comment: normally distribution ;) so at every event, it picks a random from between 1-10

Comment: I understand that it needs to pick randomly from the values `1:10`, but this is NOT a normal distribution, a normal distribution generate values in the interval `-inf` to `inf`.

Comment: I'm trying to simulate a model where one entity is Customer, and what we know is

"Interval between customer arrivals is normally 
distributed between 0 and 10 minutes"

So a new event should be fire randomly between 0-10 minutes.

Comment: Again, there is no such "normally distributed between 0 and 10 minutes". The normal distribution is unlimited. Either the exercise is wrong, or you interpreted it wrongly. My suggestion is to first _fully_ understand which distribution you want and then figure out how to generate it, rather then the other way around. Should the exercise be wrong, then you would also understand why it is wrong.

Comment: `randi(11,[1 n])-1` generates n integers in the 0-10 range. `10*rand([1 n])` generates n uniformly distributed floats in the 0-10 range. `randn([1 n])` generates 10 floats with a normal distribution (mean=0, std=1) which by definition are not bound to the 0-10 interval. The requirement is not clear as mentioned by @Nicky Mattsson